# Proper use of BEGIN and END in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I just switched from using Apache's Derby Database to MySQL and still getting familiar with the syntax. I read the documentation about triggers and I think I followed the syntax correctly. However, I'm having problems with `BEGIN` and `END` My insert trigger below doesn't work if I put `BEGIN` and `END`I even tried putting `DELIMITER` but it doesn't fix it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER COPY_INSERTED_USERID_TO_ALLUSERS_PERMISSIONS 
AFTER INSERT ON ALLUSERS 
FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ALLUSERS_ADMIN_PERMISSIONS(USERID)
            VALUES(NEW.USERID);
    END;
```

Removing the `BEGIN` and `END` makes it work but I'm not able to take full advantage of the compound statements.

```
CREATE TRIGGER COPY_INSERTED_USERID_TO_ALLUSERS_PERMISSIONS 
AFTER INSERT ON ALLUSERS 
FOR EACH ROW 

        INSERT INTO ALLUSERS_ADMIN_PERMISSIONS(USERID)
            VALUES(NEW.USERID);
```

[image]

I'd appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Edited:

I tried to follow @Ilanatos advice which works but returns an error on first attempt. I had to refresh the phpmyadmin page to get rid of the error. 
Below are the screenshots.

[image]

then if I refresh the page(both Firefox and Chrome), I see the trigger.

[image]

I don't think it should return an error message during execution of create trigger definition.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the delimiter function when creating your trigger.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER COPY_INSERTED_USERID_TO_ALLUSERS_PERMISSIONS 
AFTER INSERT ON ALLUSERS 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO ALLUSERS_ADMIN_PERMISSIONS(USERID)
        VALUES(NEW.USERID);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @Ilanato Thanks for your advice. Though the trigger shows up, there's a small problem. When I tried to recreate the trigger(after dropping it) using your code, it returns an error message as shown in the screenshot I provided.